# Helmholtz equation Inequality (potential theory)

Tags: potential-theory

I was reading the chapter about surface potential. I came across an inequality

$$|e^{ik|x_1-y|}-e^{ik|x_2-y|}|\leq k|x_1-x_2|,$$

$k$ is a complex number here. Since $k$ is a complex number here, I am a bit confused. I am wondering what is the correct way to interpret this ineuqality?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The map $z \mapsto e^z$ maps complex numbers to complex numbers. Hence $e^{ik|x_1-y|}$ is a complex number and

$$|e^{ik|x_1-y|}-e^{ik|x_2-y|}|\leq k|x_1-x_2|$$ is an inequality between complex numbers modulus.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. $|\cdot|$ gives real number and $k$ is complex. Is there any assumption involved in comparing real number and complex number?

Comment: Left and right sides of the inequality are modulus, i.e. real numbers.

Comment: Shouldn't we write $|k|$ for $k$ instead?

Comment: Well spoted! You're right. This is a mistake in the article.

Comment: Originally, I thought this is a typo. But I find another resource online. In page 104 (3.15), he used the same notation. https://www.math.kit.edu/ianmip/lehre/sobraum2014s/media/main.pdf

Comment: So I am not sure this is a typo or I have some misunderstandings.

Comment: I would guess a typo... But not 100% sure. Maybe you can contact the author?

Comment: yeah maybe, thank you!